What simulations do I need to do to analyze a tranimpedance amplifier?
I am trying to understand the working of the trans-impedance amplifier. What simulations does people generally perform to see, say the transimpedance gain. How to find the transimpedance gain from the simulations. How to get the bandwidth of working of my transimpedance amplifier? What are the other things I need to simulate to prove that it is a good transimpedance amplifier.

You model the circuit, then run a frequency sweep with the simulator. What are you amplifying? Modeling the sensor is often the most difficult part.

Thanks a lot for the reply. I want to amplify the Iin current to a voltage output. I hope this is what you asked?

I think @Mattman944 was asking what is generating the current that you want to change to a voltage, and if you want to include that in your simulation.  (E.g. is it a photodiode?)  If you just want to model the amplifier itself it's simply a matter of using an AC current source as input, running an AC simulation over frequency and dividing the output voltage by the input current from the source. But the real-world source can have a significant impact on the results, for example if there's significant capacitance.

Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. The current is being generated from a FET based sensor. Following are my specs for modelling : I am aiming for input currents between 100nA and 10 uA and output voltages between 0 and 4V. I want to work in a low-frequency bandwidth like 100Hz. How can I approach this problem, like its a kind of a large signal...what you mentioned about the analysis, will it still remain the same? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

You can use JFET or CMOS input op amp with low bias current to reduce DC errors.
Please operate within the linear output voltage swing to minimize non-linearity errors.
Regarding simulation you can do,

DC Simulation (Input current vs Output Voltage)
AC Simulation (Gain vs Frequency)
Stability Analysis

This document is a good reference for TIA stability analysis.
